# Fetching data from firebase within android

Tags: android, firebase

Say if I have my data in firebase stored as the following:

```
{
    "sensor_data": {
      "duration": 41143403,
      "activity": "unknown"
    },
    "sensor_name": "Activity",
    "timestamp": {
      "start_time": "Mon Mar 6 00:00:00 EST 2017",
      "end_time": "Mon Mar 6 11:25:44 EST 2017"
    }
  },
```

I want to get the duration value within the sensor_data object by entering a string input, comparing that string input to the start_time value within the timestamp object. How is it possible to execute a query as such? does the string input have to match exactly to the start_time value?

Answer (score 3):

Firebase can perform range queries, and even do this on strings. But it will compare the values from the start of the string. So in your `start_time` format that means you can search for all items on Monday March 6 with something like:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(...);
ref.orderByChild("timestamp/start_time").startAt("Mon Mar 6").endAt("Mon Mar 6~")...
```

But there's no way to get the child notes from March 6 to 7, since the those start with `"Tue Mar 7"`.

To allow filtering dates in a string format, you have to make sure the date format is the same in lexicographical (alphabetical) order as it is in chronological order. A great string format for that is ISO-8601, which could like like this for the same `start_date` you have: `"2020-03-06T00:00:00-04:00"`

On that you could then query for March 6 to 7 with:

```
ref.orderByChild("timestamp/start_time").startAt("2020-03-06").endAt("2020-03-07~")...
```

Also see:

- [Firebase query by date string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38216858/firebase-query-by-date-string)
- [How to retrieve data from firebase where the value of a date is 1 month ago from current date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55206491/how-to-retrieve-data-from-firebase-where-the-value-of-a-date-is-1-month-ago-from)
- [Query based on multiple where clauses in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase/26701282#26701282)
- [Querying by range in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52728669/querying-by-range-in-firebase/52732340#52732340)
- [Firebase endAt() not working with date string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40203540/firebase-endat-not-working-with-date-string/40204402#40204402)

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight and resources!